# Login issues of the services registered with AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have load balancer listening on two ports one abc and other xyz. These port redirect them to the different instances. But the instance are running the same application but with different data. The application has login page. The issue is when i access Lb with abc port and login to the application its logging out the existing application running on the other port xyz. Is there any way to make these both sessions active. Note both the instances are running same application but has different data.

The possible solution to overcome this problem

Comment: How does your application handle user sessions? Is it using session cookies? You probably just need to configure them to use different cookie names.